# Why does my "random key code" creates a same key every once in a while?

Tags: random, vbscript, asp-classic

I`m having the following code from which I extract randomPW for my db.

I need this string of random characters in order to use it a primary key in my Db. The problem is that I`m getting quite a lot of duplicates when I execute this code more than once or if I get a Loop in order to extract (for example) 100 keys at once.

If I try to reload the page in order to insert one by one key the same problem occurs... every 50-80 reloads there is a duplicate. What's wrong with my code?

```
    <%
    Function RandomPW(myLength)
    Const minLength = 6
    Const maxLength = 20

    Dim X, Y, strPW

    If myLength = 0 Then
    Randomize
    myLength = Int((maxLength * Rnd) + minLength)
    End If


    For X = 1 To myLength
    Y = Int((3 * Rnd) + 1) '(1) Numeric, (2) Uppercase, (3)   Lowercase

    Select Case Y
    Case 1
    'Numeric character
    Randomize
    strPW = strPW & CHR(Int((9 * Rnd) + 48))
    Case 2
    'Uppercase character
    Randomize
    strPW = strPW & CHR(Int((25 * Rnd) + 65))
    Case 3
    'Lowercase character
    Randomize
    strPW = strPW & CHR(Int((25 * Rnd) + 97))

    End Select
    Next    
    RandomPW = strPW
    End Function
    %>
```

I expect my code to extract a string that will not duplicate every now and then.

Comment: Why would it not be possible for something random cause duplicates?

Comment: @Amadan The [`Randomize` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//38d7ckek%28v%3dvs.85%29) in VBScript is used to seed the randomizer for the [`Rnd()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//e566zd96%28v%3dvs.85%29).

Comment: @Lankymart: Ah, that makes sense, and explains the results.

Comment: Why not just use `NEWID()` if you're using SQL Server or an equivalent for the database you're using?

Comment: I `m using MS Access and Autonumber doesn`t work for my project cause I need to move some records from one db to another...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need this string of random characters in order to use it a primary key in my Db.

In this case I would recommend to use [Scriptlet.TypeLib](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-create-a-guid-using-a-script/) :

```
Function RandomPW(myLength)
    Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    If myLength < Len(TypeLib.Guid)
      RandomPW = Left(TypeLib.Guid, myLength)
    Else
      RandomPW = TypeLib.Guid
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: your solution to my problem worked like a charm!!!! I`ll have a beer for you my friend! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 3):

`Randomize` is not supposed to be used more than once, unless you want to make sure you are creating fake, repeatable randomness. Per docs, helpfully linked by Lankymart (emphasis mine):

> `Randomize` uses number to initialize the `Rnd` function's random-number generator, giving it a new seed value. **If you omit number, the value returned by the system timer is used as the new seed value.**

The system timer referred to above is in seconds; which means, successive calls to `Randomize` in short succession will make sure the following `Rnd` is yielding the same value.

It would likely help you immensely to remove all calls to `Randomize`.

Comment: removing the "randomize" helped me create unique random values in a loop. For example I have created 1000 unique values by executing a loop. 
The problem is that executing the same loop for a second time I got exaclty the same 1000 unique values like before. So this I guess that I can not use this small script in order to get unique keys for my db. I shall stick with the answer that @duDE gave me. Thanks for your reply thou Amadan. Helped me to see clearly my mistake! :) Cheers!!

Comment: It was not a solution, just an answer to your literal question ("Can you please tell me what`s wrong with my code?"). If you want to actually _use_ something, do go the way of @duDE.